# Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/about_path"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am beginner to ror, I am trying dynamic page in my application, while I click the about link in my application I got a routing error(as said in title). Here is my routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :userdetails do
    collection {post :import}
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
root to: "userdetails#index"
get 'about', to:'userdetails#about'

 devise_scope :users do
   get 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
   get 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy' 
  end
end
```

here is index.html.erb file:

```
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="about_path" data-method = "get" >About Us</a>
...
</div>
```

Please help me identify my mistake.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your routes says: -

```
get '/about', to: 'userdetails#about', as: :user_about
```

so according to this

```
<a href="/about">About Us</a>
```

Instead of this you can use rails view helper which fill convert this to html anchor tag: -

```
<%= link_to 'About Us', user_about_path%>
```

As you are beginner so you should go though this [rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for better clarification.

Note: - by default link is `GET` type http verb so you don't need to mention `data-method = "get"`
and you can see all your routes at console by running command `rake routes`

Answer (score 2):

When you run `rails routes` or `rake routes` it will generate like this

```
about GET    /about(.:format)            userdetails#about
```

That means your path is `about_path` then you can call out like this

```
<a href="<%= about_path %>">About Us</a>
```

or like this HTML

```
<a href="/about">About Us</a>
```

or like this `.erb`

```
<%= link_to 'About Us', about_path %>
```

While your routes like exist

```
get 'about', to:'userdetails#about'
```

Here you have defined method `get` that's why this is unnecessary to HTML call out `data-method = "get"`.

Hope it will work